# MiniDumpWriteDump execution error on Windows 7

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, minidump, minidumpwritedump

I have a task to collect dumps of running processes in windows. For this purpose I use MiniDumpWriteDump function. I have no problems with this function on OS older than Windows 7. However, recently it stopped working on vindows 7. I had previously encountered implementation problems for version 7, then I had to set exceptionInfo.ClientPointers = TRUE; For systems older than 7: exceptionInfo.ClientPointers = FALSE; But now the MiniDumpWriteDump call returns 0. I tried to get the error code using EXCEPTION_POINTERS. But I'm getting back a value of 148696056, which doesn't match any [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-exception_record).

```
      for( const auto& process : GetActiveProcesses() )
      {
         if( process.ExeFile() == mProcessName )
         {
            try
            {
               String dump_name = GetDumpFileName( process.ProcessID() );
               bfs::wpath dump_path = assembly_directory / dump_name;

               MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION exceptionInfo = { 0 };
               if( IsWindows8OrGreater() )
                   exceptionInfo.ClientPointers = FALSE;
               else
                   exceptionInfo.ClientPointers = TRUE;

               HANDLE hProcess =
                  ::OpenProcess( PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, process.ProcessID() );
               exceptionInfo.ThreadId = GetThreadId(hProcess) ;
               EXCEPTION_POINTERS exceptionPointers;
               exceptionInfo.ExceptionPointers = &exceptionPointers;
               if( hProcess == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
               {
                  // error log
               }
               HANDLE hDumpFile = ::CreateFile( dump_path.wstring().c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS,
                                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );
               if( hDumpFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
               {
                  ::CloseHandle( hProcess );
                  // error log
               }
               auto res =
                  ::MiniDumpWriteDump( hProcess, process.ProcessID(), hDumpFile,
                                       ( MINIDUMP_TYPE )( MiniDumpNormal | MiniDumpWithIndirectlyReferencedMemory |
                                                          MiniDumpWithDataSegs | MiniDumpWithFullMemory ),
                                       &exceptionInfo, nullptr, nullptr );
               ::CloseHandle( hProcess );
               ::CloseHandle( hDumpFile );
               if( res )
               {
                  // work with dump
               }
               else
               {
                  bfs::remove( dump_path );
                  DWORD exceptionCode = exceptionInfo.ExceptionPointers->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode;
                  String result = L"";
                  switch (exceptionCode)
                      {
                          case EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION:
                              result = L"Access Violation Exception";
                              break;
                          case EXCEPTION_ARRAY_BOUNDS_EXCEEDED:
                              result = L"Array Bounds Exceeded Exception";
                              break;
                          case EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT:
                              result = L"Breakpoint Exception";
                              break;
                          case EXCEPTION_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT:
                              result = L"Datatype Misalignment Exception";
                              break;
                          case EXCEPTION_FLT_DENORMAL_OPERAND:
                              result = L"Floating Point Denormal Operand Exception";
                              break;
                          case EXCEPTION_FLT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO:
                              result = L"Floating Point Divide By Zero Exception";
                              break;
                          case EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION:
                              result = L"Illegal Instruction Exception";
                              break;
                          case EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR:
                              result = L"In Page Error Exception";
                              break;
                          case EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO:
                              result = L"Integer Divide By Zero Exception";
                              break;
                          case EXCEPTION_INVALID_DISPOSITION:
                              result = L"Invalid Disposition Exception";
                              break;
                          case EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE_EXCEPTION:
                              result = L"Noncontinuable Exception";
                              break;
                          case EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION:
                              result = L"Privileged Instruction Exception";
                              break;
                          case EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW:
                              result = L"Stack Overflow Exception";
                              break;
                          default:
                              result = L"Unknown Exception";
                              break;
                      }
                  ErrorMsg( Format( L"Error type: %1%"_sv, result ) );
               }
            }
            catch( ... )
            {
               // error log
            }
         }
      }
```

Comment: `GetThreadId(hProcess)` is meaningless. You cannot get a thread ID from a process handle.

Comment: Why do you even have `exceptionInfo`, it seems useless here since you don't have an exception.

Comment: Since `MiniDumpWriteDump` returns 0. Why don't you just call `GetLastError()`. But note that the last error will be an `HRESULT` value.